# Yamllint exclude @ symbol check in application.yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, properties, yaml, lint, yamllint

I have used linter to lint spring-boot framework `application.yaml` file:

```yaml
---
spring:
  application:
    name: @project.name@
```

`@project.name@` value allows spring-boot application to resolve application name from `pom.xml` file.
However when I run [linter](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint)  (`yamllint ./src/main/`) I get an error:
`Error: ./src/main/resources/application.yaml:4:11: [error] syntax error: found character '@' that cannot start any token (syntax)`

---

**Is there any rule how can I exclude special characters check?**

Answer (score 1):

That's a syntax error. `yamllint` uses PyYAML for parsing, which yields this error. PyYAML obviously cannot ignore a syntax error, and by extension, yamllint cannot ignore it.

Your best bet is to preprocess the file to replace all referenced variables, e.g.

```
sed -E 's/@([^@]*)@/_\1_/g' application.yaml | yamllint -
```

This replaces the `@` characters around variable references with `_`, which keeps the line length.